# Get HTTPBadRequest 400 with ruby net/http

Tags: ruby, api, httprequest, net-http, chatbot

I'm trying to write a Chatbot in Ruby. I'm currently facing a problem with the http request. Is this even the right way to do a request or do I have to search my fault in an other section of the code? I'm also using a proxy, could this affect the http request?

That's my request:

```
def makeRequest(urlToCheck)
    uri = URI.parse('https://somesite/api/lookup/url')
    http = Net::HTTP::new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new('https://somesite/api/lookup/url')
    request.initialize_http_header({"X-PMAN-KEY" => "fdsgdfsgdf"}).to_json
    request.content_type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    data = URI.encode_www_form({"url" => "#{urlToCheck}","userAgent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/ 40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36"})
    request.body = data
    @response= http.request(request)
    puts request

#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>
```

Comment: do you have an error message from the server?

Comment: @Gavriel The error is coming from the server.

Comment: I know, that's why I asked if you could show us the error messages

Comment: I solved it, forgot to send it as a JSON:   return JSON.parse(response.body)